# PhpMailer sends to gmail but not to hotmail accounts

Tags: php, web, phpmailer

I know this has been asked before, but i wanted to show my case because i tried to solve it with other answers but i coundt solve it.

I m trying to do a Contact form but when i choose the email of the receiver if i choose  @hotmail.com or @advancedinstitute.cl they dont receive the email.
I tried to choose another type of email like gmail, yahoo or terra and the email arrives without problem.

I know it must be because the spam policies of those servers but i dont know how to fix it.

This is my code of the phpMailer:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->Hostname = "Advanced Institute";
$mail->From = $_POST["email"];
$mail->FromName = $_POST["email"];
$mail->Subject = "Quiero contactarme con Advanced Institute";
$mail->AddAddress("carmeng.advanced@terra.cl","Advanced Institute");
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["email"]);
$mail->IsHTML(true); // El correo se envía como HTML
$body = '<html><body><div>Nombre : '.$_POST["nombre"].'<br>  Email :    '.$_POST["email"].'<br>  Telefono : '.$_POST["telefono"].'<br>  Asunto : '.$_POST["asunto"].'<br>  Comentarios:           '.$_POST["comentarios"].'<br> </div></body></html>';
$mail->Body = $body;    
    if(!$mail->Body) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }else{
    $mail->Send();
```

I hope my english was enough for you guys to understand my problem.
THANK YOU IN ADVANCED

Comment: Did you check for spam? sometimes "automatic" mails are either classified or considered spam. Also, are you getting any error or is it going fluent?

Comment: its because your `From` is from an e-mail address not associated with your server!!!!

Comment: @briosheje Nothing in the spam folder, and also i m not getting any error in the phpmailer everything goes smooth.

Comment: As @cmorrissey said, you should not set your from address like that - put your own address in from, put the sender's address in reply-to, as you're already doing. It also looks like you have based your code on an old example. Get the latest PHPMailer and examples [on github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to set up SPF records for the domain name.

Further information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework

Recommended SPF Wizard http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html

Also the from address should be from the sending domain name, not user input.

Comment: Don't use Microsoft's SPF checker - it produces incorrect results. Use [Scott Kitterman's SPF validator](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html) instead.

Comment: I got the SPF code but i dont know how to add it to my hosting.

Comment: @Synchro it says that my domain already has an SPF and that is valid.:S